# Is downloading educational videos through torrents haram if they are ordinarily viewable online?

Tags: halal-haram, piracy, internet

I have a subscription of a site from where I can see educational videos. That site doesn't have the functionality to download these contents so that I can check it later. They do offer offline caching but with some extra charges.

Most of the contents are available on the web through torrents. My question is, is it permissible to download these through torrents?

<sub>Note: I have the right to check it online if net is available.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the copyright details on their videos. More precisely, it seem like they are charging for a service you would be getting otherwise for free, if you torrent them. So, If you are still confused, then it would be best to email them for their opinion. In Islam educators are held in high regards; our relationship with them is equivalent to a slave to his master. Eloquently said by Imam Ali:

> "I am a slave of he who teaches me one letter of the alphabet. If he
>   wishes, he may sell me; if he so desires, he may set me free; and if
>   he cares to, he may deploy me as a slave"
>   [Source](http://www.sunniforum.com/forum/showthread.php?71446-Urdu-meaning/page71)

Bil Tawfik!

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not permissible to download these through torrents.

The teacher and producer of these videos have worked on it and they'd hope that they would get some income from these videos. But when you download or copy it without their permission then it is like you've robbed their money. It's like you get a worker for a building, and when he is done, you don't pay him.